# dont know what this function does

Tags: postgresql

I have a database that is named Dvdrental and in that database there is a function that is named public.film_not_in_stock, but I don't understand what it does.

```
-- Function: public.film_not_in_stock(integer, integer)

-- DROP FUNCTION public.film_not_in_stock(integer, integer);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.film_not_in_stock(
IN p_film_id integer,
IN p_store_id integer,
OUT p_film_count integer)


RETURNS SETOF integer AS

$BODY$
SELECT inventory_id
FROM inventory
WHERE film_id = $1
AND store_id = $2
AND NOT inventory_in_stock(inventory_id);
$BODY$

  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION public.film_not_in_stock(integer, integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Looks like it checks inventory to see if the id of the film appears for a given store id.  What's confusing about that?

Comment: But what does it do after that? Because this is a function and it has to do something?

Comment: A function (in the sense Postgres uses) takes some input, and returns some output, and might additionally have side-effects. In this case, the input is the parameters `p_film_id` and `p_store_id`, and the output is the results of that `SELECT` statement.

Comment: It returns the films that are not on stock

Comment: How do i trigger the function?

Comment: The OUT variable is  p_film_count.  If it's zero, it's not in stock.  If it is positive, it's in stock.

Comment: @duffymo That might have been the original intention, but it's not what this code does. If I understand [the manual page on SQL functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#xfunc-output-parameters) correctly, `p_film_count` will simply be the name of the column in the output, which will actually contain the individual `inventory_id` values.

Comment: I thought OUT parameter was the return value from the function.  It's an integer value; that's not a list.

Comment: @duffymo Read the section I just linked to, and also this one: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#xfunc-sql-functions-returning-set `OUT` parameters on `sql` (rather than `plpgsql`) functions are apparently just another way of defining the output types and field names. It's not just a single integer, because the function is declared with `RETURNS SETOF integer`. Nor is there anything in the query to perform a `COUNT` operation, so if it did return a single integer, it would be the value of `inventory_id` from some row. Don't be fooled by bad variable names.

Comment: @duffymo Your description of the output is wrong in another way too: a count if it was returned would be the number of copies *not* in stock, so zero would mean "every copy owned is in stock", and any other value would mean "some are currently rented", but you couldn't actually determine if there were any that *were* in stock. Even a value of zero wouldn't guarantee that, since there might simply be no copies owned.

Comment: Fooled, indeed.  Sounds like you're on top of it, @IMSoP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a `LANGUAGE SQL` function. Not plpgsql.

SQL-language functions implicitly return the results of the last query they run.

Your function, if it was rewritten in plpgsql, would do

```
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY 
      SELECT inventory_id
      FROM inventory
      WHERE film_id = $1
      AND store_id = $2
      AND NOT inventory_in_stock(inventory_id);
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

but in a `LANGUAGE SQL` function the `RETURN` is implicit.